# How do I get the sizes display in square boxes instead of drop down list in magento 1.8?

Tags: php, magento-1.8

I want size option in square box instead of drop down in magento 1.8!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to make a module to change the dropdown to radio buttons instead, witch you can then style with CSS.  There is several guides out there, but here's a link to one that is fairly complete and even has a download link for the package:

http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/configurable-product-modification-in-magento/

What you need to do after successfully installed that is to write up the CSS to style it as boxes.